# Class cast exception by onclick listener in android

Tags: android

I have written a code to implement onclick events of buttons in android.
I have written the following line to set the listener in oncreate method.
I want to recognize the touch event of a button in the application.i am getting a class cast exception in android.

mybtn[i].setOnClickListener( (OnClick Lisener)this);

for the alternatives to recognize the ontouch event i have looked at the SetKeylistener() , setonkeylistener() and setontouchlistener() methods. but i am not getting which one to use exactly.

What exactly i want to achieve is TTS should speak the number when the button is touched, and on the key release that number should be added to some textbox. so what methods should i use to accomplish these things.

Answer (score 1):

You should accomplish the effect by doing this:

```
    mybtn[i].setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
    {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1)
        {
            switch (arg1.getAction())
            {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    // Do some stuff
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    // Do some stuff
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: what is the difference between click and touch events i am not getting . will u please explain to me. and as well how to recognize the key release event...

Comment: Click = Down and then Up (both events as one event). Touch is single event: Down/Up/Move etc...

Answer (score 0):

use View.OnClickListener if you use setOnClickListener.

To accomplish your purpose you can btn.setOnTouchListener and do something according to the MotionEvent,such as event.getAction=MotionEvent.ACTION_UP ...

for example:

```
btn.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

            }
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement interface in your activity class which ever listener you want to listen on button, like for onClickListener

```
public class A extends Activity implments OnClickListener
```

Comment: yaa i got it thanks, but what methods should i use to handle touch event, key release event can u tell me about that. One more thing is i did not get the difference between touch and click events. Both look like same to me. what is the difference between them.

Comment: onClick(View v) must be overrided to implement onClickListener, to implement onTouchListener method public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event), and difference between onTouch and onClick is touch has all the touch events on a component including click, long-click, move events.

Comment: thanks for ur suggestion ,but it is not working right now. it is not giving any error as well.here is my code (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9326975/onclick-event-not-working-in-android)