# Onclick event not working in android

Tags: android

I have written a code to enter some text using button click events in android. It is not working at all. Not giving any error or exception,i am not getting where it is all going wrong.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    //select_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ok);
    //home_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.home);
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.entry);
    et.setText("", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE );
    b = new Bundle();

    for (int i = 0; i < mybtn.length; i++) {
        String btnid = "btn" + i;
        int resid = getResources().getIdentifier(btnid, "id",
                getPackageName());
        mybtn[i] = (Button) findViewById(resid);
        mybtn[i].setOnClickListener(this);          
    }       
    //tts.speak("hello wolrd",TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);
    et.setText("hello man", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE );     
}

public void onClick(View v)
{

    //while(tts.isSpeaking());
    et.setText("hello android", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE );
    String s=null;
    s = ((Button)v).getText().toString().trim();
    //tts.speak("hello google",TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);      
}
```

here is the main.xml :

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/entry"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:focusable="false"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:maxLength="20" />

<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/table"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/entry"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:stretchColumns="*" >

    <TableRow>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn0"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/zero"
            android:textSize="10pt"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/one"
            android:textSize="10pt"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/two"
            android:textSize="10pt"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/three"
            android:textSize="10pt"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </TableRow>

    <View
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="#FF909090" />

    <TableRow>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/four"
            android:textSize="10pt"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/five"
            android:textSize="10pt"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/six"
            android:textSize="10pt"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/seven"
            android:textSize="10pt"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </TableRow>

    <View
        android:layout_height="2dip"
        android:background="#FF909090" />

    <TableRow>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn8"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/eight"
            android:textSize="10pt"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn9"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/nine"
            android:textSize="10pt"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/delete"
            android:textSize="10pt"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight=".25"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/finish"
            android:textSize="10pt"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>

<View
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:layout_below="@id/table" >
</View>
```

Comment: please post your whole code here only java file

Comment: have u implement onclicklistner on the class?

Comment: i have implemented the onclicklistener , otherwise i would have got an error.

Comment: Guys please suggest me something ,i need to sort out this one and have to do a lot of things

Comment: thanks guys, i got the solution.the thing i am doing  is i am clicking it on single time. it is responding when i double click on a button, but in some previous codes i have implemented the oncliclicklistener with anonymous class and it worked with single click. i am shocked because i could not predict it. i am not understanding why it is behaving like this

Comment: this is my new observation that when u implement onclicklistener using anonymus class it works on a single click ,else double click is needed.

Comment: @user1208937 What you describe sounds very WEIRD (that would be a huge bug). I don't use anonymous classes to define my onClick() functions, and NEVER had to double-click a button to activate it.

Comment: Why havn't you marked any of the answers ?

Answer (score 3):

In your code you are passing the activity into the `setOnClickListener()` method by `mybtn[i].setOnClickListener(this)` where `this` is a reference to your activity. The `setOnClickListener()` expects as a parameter a `View.OnClickListener` interface. That is any object that implements the `View.OnClickListener` Interface. There are two ways that you might do this.

1) Create an anonymous object e.g.

```
  mybtn[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ... your code here
     }
  });
```

the new `OnClickListener()` creates an anonymous object, it is anonymous because we do not store a reference to it.

2) Pass in an object that implements the `View.OnClickListener()`. If you wanted to pass in your activity object to `setOnClickListener()` you would have to have it declare that it implements `View.OnClickListener()` and additionally Override the `public void onClick(View v)` method e.g.

```
public class YourActvivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    onCreate() {
    }
    ....etc

    //implement the View.OnClickListener interface
    @Override
    public void on Click(View v) {
         ...your code here
    }
```

because you have an array of buttons and calling `setOnClickListener(this)` where `this` is your activity this one method will be called for each of your buttons, so if you want each button to do something different you would have to compare the view id that was the source of the click event with the button id in your xml, otherwise all buttons will behave in exactly the same way when clicked.

to find out which button was clicked you can check like this

```
   switch(v.getId()) {
   case R.id.btn0:
       ...do button 0 stuff;
   break;
   case R.id.btn1:
      ...do button 1 stuff;
   break;
   ...etc
   }
```

the view that is passed into the `onClick()` callback is the view that the click event originated from and is referenced here simply as `v onClick(View v)`. This second method will work for any object (Class) that declares and implements `View.OnClickListener`.

Answer (score 1):

****UPDATE****

Oh sorry...

I think you have a problem with your listener registration, try this instead :

```
b=findViewById(R.id.btnid);
b.setOnClickListener(this);

b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View view) {
         et.setText("hello android", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE );
         String s=null;
         s = ((Button)v).getText().toString().trim();
    }

});
```

Comment: harry i want to capture the event of clicking button,but not the edit text

Comment: attach the listener to the button instead then.

Comment: i have done it yaar,u can see it from the code .but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

In the layout add:

```
android:onClick="onClick"
```

to the Button on which you want to handle click...

Comment: i want to use the onlciklistener method ,please tell me what is the problem with above approach.because i will implement a layout which has lot of buttons.so i prefer above method

Comment: You have written this:  `mybtn[i].setOnClickListener(this);`  `this` here refers to Activity!! not an onclickListener

Comment: but i am implementing onclicklistener , so it must work and i have seen this way of implementation at so many places

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the text of the clicked button to a string variable, but not using it.
This should be more like what you are trying to achieve:

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
    // et.setText("hello android", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE );
    String s=null;
    s = ((Button)v).getText().toString().trim();


    et.setText(s, TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE );   
}
```

Comment: i have set the text to "hello world". that is also not working yaar, forget about string.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your activity is like below

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
Button b;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    //select_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ok);
    //home_btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.home);
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.entry);
    et.setText("", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE );

    b=findViewById(R.id.btnid);
    b.setOnClickListener(this);
    b = new Bundle();

    for (int i = 0; i < mybtn.length; i++) {
        String btnid = "btn" + i;
        int resid = getResources().getIdentifier(btnid, "id",
                getPackageName());
        mybtn[i] = (Button) findViewById(resid);
        mybtn[i].setOnClickListener(this);          
    }       
    //tts.speak("hello wolrd",TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);
    et.setText("hello man", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE );     
}

public void onClick(View v)
{
    if(v.equals(b))
{
    //while(tts.isSpeaking());
    et.setText("hello android", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE );
    String s=null;
    s = ((Button)v).getText().toString().trim();
    //tts.speak("hello google",TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH,null);     
} 
}
}
```

Comment: i am not getting your code. what is the need of comparison in onclick method v.equals(b). i am using it in a general way

Comment: whithout v.equals(b) also works if you write onclick listener for one view in your activity otherwise you have to check which view is clicked

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
     {
       ............
        int[] mybtn = new int[] {R.id.btn1,......R.id.btn11};
        for(int i=0; i<mybtn.length; i++) {
        Button b = (Button) findViewById(mybtn[i]);
        b.setOnClickListener(this); 
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

In

```
onCreate()
```

method you should have to mention

```
et.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Then override  the

```
onClick(View v)
{
  //Your code here
}
```

This will work!